# Node JS. How to send email without third-party mail server

Tags: node.js, smtp, nodemailer

I need to send (and maybe in the future also receive) email to Node JS without the help of third party servers (such as gmail).
I found `node-mailer-direct-transport`, but it looks like it is outdated and unsupported.
Is it possible to send email directly using Node JS without a mail server, if not, is it possible to create a mail server locally using Node JS?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [maildev](https://github.com/maildev/maildev). It is a good thing to use the locally easy to build in your environments.

And [here](https://github.com/cyber-eternal/docker-compose-examples/blob/master/maildev/docker-compose.yml) is the docker-compose example to run maildev in container